# How to create website as per my layout without website template.?

Tags: html, css, templates

I want to create a website but i don't know html and CSS . I have submitted my website layout to the teachers but i don't no how i will create that website look like layout.. so what can i do ? Is their any software  like blue griffon etc (blue griffon is not good i didn't understand)

This is my small project to do but i don't no how can i do my classmates is doing this Good because they know html and css

[image]

Comment: Either learn HTML and CSS, or use [one of many website builders out there](https://www.google.com/search?dcr=0&source=hp&q=website+builder&oq=website+builder). If you don't want to do either, then paying someone to do it for you is always an option. However, don't expect anyone on SO to do it for you for free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From looking at your template, I assume that you are using Microsoft Word? There are [methods which allows you to convert Word documents to HTML](http://www.wikihow.com/Convert-a-Word-Document-to-HTML) online. While they may not reproduce the standards of what a HTML and CSS webpage would be written from scratch, it will allow you to view the document in your browser, and edit in a text editor.

If you need to use a site builder, there are websites freely available such as Squarespace and Webflow (Which is a bit more advanced). And there is also the option of you learning HTML and CSS yourself. There are many websites, YouTube videos and books to help you get started.